# Compare 2 row with awk

Tags: awk

I'like to print all second field from rows in one row if their first field is identical. The amount of first identical filed are undefined

Example

```
1 abc    
1 def    
1 ghi    
2 abc    
3 abc    
3 def
```

Desired output

```
1 abc def ghi    
2 abc    
3 abc def
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input is sorted:

```
$ awk 'p!=$1{if(NR>1) print r;p=r=$1}
{r=(r OFS $2)} END{print r}' file
1 abc def ghi
2 abc
3 abc def
```

- For each line;

  1. If its first column is equal to `p` (i.e first column of previous line);

     1. If line number (`NR`) is bigger than 1; print `r`.
     2. Populate `p` and `r` with first column's value.
  2. Add a space (`OFS`) and second column's value to `r`.
- At the end of the file, print `r`.

Comment: @MichelWegmueller tried to explain, hope you get it.

Comment: Hi @oguzismail, I run this command with a lot of print statement for variables in each {} and understood now who this works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, it will also provide you output in same form in which 1st field of Input_file has come.

```
awk '
!a[$1]++{
  b[++count]=$1
}
{
  c[$1]=(c[$1]?c[$1] OFS $2:$2)
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print b[i],c[b[i]]
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score -1):

Another awk

```
$ cat michael.txt
1 abc
1 def
1 ghi
2 abc
3 abc
3 def
$ awk  ' { c=$1; if(p!=c && NR>1 ) { print p,b,a;b="" } if(p==c) { b=b " "a} p=c;a=$2 } END { print p,b,a } ' michael.txt
1  abc def ghi
2  abc
3  abc def
```